# VSCode Python error in importing modules from subdirectories

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, importerror

My project file structure is like this,

```
project/src/test/myscript.py
project/src/utils/file_utils.py
```

When I run `myscript.py`, which has `from utils import file_utils`, it gave me error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'

Previously in Pycharm IDE I did not get this type of error (maybe due to _ init _.py), the subdirs of the same parent dir could be detected. But not sure for VSCode, is there something I need to add for specifying the file structure? And I opened the folder `project` as my VSCode workspace (not sure if where I open the workspace matters)

I tried adding:

1. in the `/project/.vscode/launch.json`

```
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
```

2. or in the begining of `myscript.py`

```
import sys
import os
src_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('/project/src/'))
sys.path.insert(0, src_path)
```

But none of them works. Does anyone have any insights? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider placing a .env file at the root of your project which adds your source directory to PYTHONPATH. i.e. something like

```bash
>>> cat /project/.env
PYTHONPATH=/project/src/
>>>
```

Your code will look a smidgen nicer without the explicit manipulation of sys.path.

VSCode's usage of .env files is [documented here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file).

Comment: It works when I enter the absolute path as PYTHONPATH, ie. `/home/user/...../project/src/`
and the `.env` need to place inside the `/src` folder in my case.
And in VSCode, I opened the folder `/src` in the file explorer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in Pycharm you didn't get this error because it adds `__init__.py` file automatically when you create a python module. The python identifies the structure of your project through these files, if your folder does not have `__init__.py` python will understand it as just any folder.

Answer (score -1):

Unlike pycharm, vscode uses the **workspace as the root directory** to retrieve files. The first method you try is to write it in the **launch.json** file, which is applicable to debug rather than running it directly. You can use the following code to import:

```
from src.utils import file_utils
```

Comment: But OP wants to import `utils`, not to import `src.utils`.